# Modelling a LED Array for SPICE simualtion

Tags: led, diodes, simulation, ltspice, spice

I am currently looking to model a whole LED array within LTSPICE. I am working on all of hte logistics right now.

I currently have a LED array with about 300 LEDs on the array. Instead of modelling each LED, I figured that I get the IV curve of all of the LEDS when the array is turned on.

I currently have the data points and thus the IV curve of the LED Array. NOw what do with it.I thought that a simple solution would be to simulate the Diode part through the use of a look-up table.

In order to model the array, I was thinking that I could create a table of the IV points of the array (which I have have) and use a lookup table in combination with the VCVS. THE VCVS would use the look-up table in order to determine the output current of the VCVS.

However,  I was wondering if the VCVS is able to take a table as a parameter? I was thinking that I could use the table command but not 100% sure. Any guidance on the this matter is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT:

For clarity, I obtained a plot of IV curve from the LED array

Comment: VCxS sources can take it: `table({input1},{output1},{input2},{output2},...)`, where the curly braces are not needed for numbers, but are needed for parameters (e.g. `.param x1=1 y1=2 x2=3 y2=4`, then you'd write `table({x1},{y1},{x2},{y2})`). You can also use B-sources for that, they are extremely versatile in terms of mathematical expressions, so you could add your curve fit formula for better smoothness, but, if you can use `table()`, use VCxS sources, as they do not suffer from dynamic range limitations (where it exceeds a few orders of magnitude).

Comment: There are simpler ways to model any LED by **Vf=Vth + If*ESR** and  xPyS array by design goals (many choices) What did you choose?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I did not use those methods. Basically, I have a LED array with unkown LEDs. The LEDS came from China and there is no datasheet for them. I collected points for the IV curve by setting a known voltage and recording the current and changing the voltage. I would like to implement a VCxS with the lookup table in order to mostly accurate model the LED

Comment: @philm If accurate is your concern, then use a curve fit and implement it in a behavioural source. I would suggest a current source over a voltage one, because it also allows for the optional parasitics `Rpar` and/or `Cpar`, which help convergence.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thank you for the suggestion. I did attempt a curve fitting approach previously. I would typically get decently good accuracy near the turn on voltage but the accuracy would decrease towards the top. This would happen vice-versa.